# What's the difference between "good sense" ( ) and "common sense"?

Tags: terminology, pascal, philosophical-comparison, commonsense, bon-sens

What's the difference between "good sense" (Pascal's "*bon sens*") and "common sense"?

Comment: Not sure if bon sens is a specific concept in Pascal's writings, but if we go by the dictionary "bon sens" is just equivalent to "common sense".

Comment: looks like you want to trace the history of usage rather than philsosophy? mayb eif yo unarrowed it into something it would look a lot better :) but then i am unintersted in pascal

Comment: @armand Italian distinguishes them, too: _buon senso_ vs. _senso comune_. Is "common sense" also "good sense" or _vice versa_? Also, in scholastic philosophy, [_sensus comunis_](https://www.corpusthomisticum.org/it/index.age?results.pageSize=50&text=%3Dsensus+%3Dcommunis) is the nexus of all sense data, where visual, auditory, etc., data come together.

Comment: See [here](http://www.penseesdepascal.fr/General/Lebonsens.php): "Le *bon sens* renvoie à Descartes et au début du *Discours de la méthode* [refers to Descartes and the beginning of] .... La référence se comprend sans peine, puisque Pascal, non sans ironie, considère Descartes comme le « docteur de la raison »."

Comment: [Discourse](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Discourse_on_the_Method/Part_1): "*Le bon sens* is, of all things among men, the most equally distributed; for every one thinks himself so abundantly provided with it, that those even who are the most difficult to satisfy in everything else, do not usually desire a larger measure of this quality than they already possess. "

Comment: [Common Sense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Sense) is more in the anglo-saxon tradition.

Comment: See [Thomas Reid](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/reid/) and [Thomas Paine](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/paine/). As you can see, it is linked to *reason* and not (scholastic) senses.